# Список Spinner с дополнительными параметрами

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Как сделать Spinner с дополнительными параметрами? Например, в списке `Spinner` есть названия операторов МТС, Билайн и т.д. Выбираем Билайн, нажимаем, допустим, на кнопку отправки SMS, а в смс приходит "1.Beeline 2.interne 3.apn и т.д. То есть отображается имя Билайн в списке, а информации больше, чем просто видим в списке.

UPD в смс отправляет только название оператора:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А надо формат смски 0000*ip1*socket1*ip2*socket2*apn
Вот Operator.java

```
public class Operator {
  public String opname;
  public String ip1;
  public String socket1;
  public String ip2;
  public String socket2;
  public String apn;

public Operator(String opname, String ip1, String socket1, String ip2, String socket2, String apn) {
    this.opname = opname;
    this.ip1 = ip1;
    this.socket1 = socket1;
    this.ip2 = ip2;
    this.socket2 = socket2;
    this.apn = apn;
    }

//То что возвращает этот метод ArrayAdapter покажет в списке
@Override
public String toString() {
    return opname;
 }
}

//То что возвращает этот метод ArrayAdapter покажет в списке
@Override
public String toString() {
    return opname;
}
```

}

Вот фрагмент Activity.java

```
    //-------------------------------------SMS Send-------------------------  --------------------
    sms = (Button) findViewById(R.id.smssend);
    sms.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendSmsMessage(telnumber.getText().toString(), objnumber.getText().toString() + "*"
            +operator.ip1 + "*" + operator.socket2 );
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Если более внимательно посмотреть на принятый ответ, то там
`new ArrayAdapter<Operator>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, operators);`

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил

Comment: надо не саму модель отправлять в СМС , а извлекать из нее нужные данные .  operator.ip1 , operator.apn и тд.

Comment: если отправляю operator.ip1 и т.д. то то что после точки - подчеркивает красным

Comment: очевидно , вы , как и в примере ,объявили поля модели как private ? Либо сделайте их public , либо используйте геттеры\сеттеры для доступа к приватным полям класса

Comment: сделал, для них не работает getSelectedItem

Comment: Исправьте в вопросе , что вы там сделали . Права доступа к полям или геттеры модели никак не должны влиять на getSelectedItem

Comment: Проблему решил - сделав это все дело через БД, выложу код может кому в будущем поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пишете модель

```
 public class Operator {
    private String name;
    private String otherField;

    public Operator(String name, String otherField) {
        this.name = name;
        this.otherField = otherField;
    }

    //То что возвращает этот метод ArrayAdapter покажет в списке
    @Override
    public String toString() { 
        return name;
    }
}
```

---

```
//Формируете список операторов, которые будут в спинере
ArrayList<Operator> operators = new ArrayList<Operrator>;
Operator operator = new Operator("Билайн", "Другое поле"); 
operators.add(operator);

Operator operator2 = new Operator("МТС", "Другое поле2"); 
operators.add(operator2);

//Адаптер
ArrayAdapter<Operator> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Operator>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, operators);
```

---

```
Operator operator = (Operator)spinner.getSelectedItem();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Очень доходчиво и понятно! Заодно и модели больше понял как создавать

Answer (score 0):

Храните дополнительные данные отдельно , например: в двумерном массиве , в коллекции объектов, БД или в любой другой милой вашему сердцу структуре , позволяющей упорядочить набор данных по индивидуальному номеру. Получайте к ним доступ по номеру позиции нажатой в Spinner.

Если использовать БД для заполнения данными пунктов спиннера в адаптере , то можно сделать связывание с дополнительными данными и выборка несколько упроститься

Comment: а не подскажете какие то уроки по этому методу? или как это лучше реализовать

Comment: [подскажу](http://www.google.ru/search?ie=UTF-8&hl=ru&q=android%20spinner) , как лучше реализовать решать вам , я не знаю , какие вы там задачи решаете , как собираетесь хранить данные и тд.

Answer (score 0):

Решение этой проблемы через базу данных:
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Справочник стран"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    </TextView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Все записи"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
    </Button>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="SMS Send"
        android:id="@+id/smssend"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
    final String LOG_TAG = "mLogs";

    String name[] = { "MTSOne", "MTS Two", "Kyivstar", "Life" };
    String ip1[] = { "192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2", "192.168.1.3", "192.168.1.4" };
    String socket1[] = { "1000", "2000", "3000", "4000" };

    Button btnAll, smssend;
    Spinner spinner;

    DBHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAll);
        btnAll.setOnClickListener(this);

        smssend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.smssend);
        smssend.setOnClickListener(this);

        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> ok1Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, name);

        ok1Adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(ok1Adapter);

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        // подключаемся к базе
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        // проверка существования записей
        Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.getCount() == 0) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            // заполним таблицу
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                cv.put("name", name[i]);
                cv.put("ip1", ip1[i]);
                cv.put("socket1", socket1[i]);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "id = " + db.insert("mytable", null, cv));
            }
        }
        c.close();
        dbHelper.close();
        // эмулируем нажатие кнопки btnAll
        onClick(btnAll);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {

        // подключаемся к базе
        db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        // данные с экрана
        String sName = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        // переменные для query

        String selection = null;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;

        // курсор
        Cursor c = null;

        // определяем нажатую кнопку
        switch (v.getId()) {
            // Все записи
            case R.id.btnAll:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Все записи ---");
                c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);
                break;
            case R.id.smssend:
                selection = "name = ?";
                selectionArgs = new String[] { sName };
                c = db.query("mytable", null, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    int ip1ColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("ip1");
                    int socket1ColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("socket1");
                 //   int ip2ColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("ip2");
                 //   int socket2ColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("socket2");
                 //   int apnColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("apn");

                    sendSmsMessage("+380676711761", c.getString(ip1ColIndex) + "*"
                            + c.getString(socket1ColIndex) + "*" );
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS Sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); }
                else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Такого об'єкту не знайдено", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
                break;
        }

        if (c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                String str;
                do {
                    str = "";
                    for (String cn : c.getColumnNames()) {
                        str = str.concat(cn + " = "
                                + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(cn)) + "; ");
                    }
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, str);

                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
        } else
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Cursor is null");

        dbHelper.close();
    }

    class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            // конструктор суперкласса
            super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
        }

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");
            // создаем таблицу с полями
            db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
                    + "id integer primary key autoincrement," + "name text,"
                    + "ip1 integer," + "socket1 text" + ");");
        }

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }

    private void sendSmsMessage(String address, String message) {
        SmsManager SMSMgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
        SMSMgr.sendTextMessage(address, null, message, null, null);

    }
}
```

Comment: нда ... Во первых , раз уж вы решили использовать БД, то и адаптер привязывайте к курсору , используйте , к примеру , `SimpleCursorApapter` . потом `setOnItemSelectedListener` - `onItemSelected` привязанный к Спиннеру будет возвращать ID записи , по которой был клик  - по этому ID вы получите недостающие данные из БД - все это во много упростит код